# How to add row into the table using Handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I am totally new to the handlebar.js so require help from expert to achieve my task.

I have a Html table which is already created through jsp.
Now how can i dynamically add new row to the table using handlebar.js?

Html structure

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="one">one</td>
<td class="two">two</td>
<td class="three">three</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="one">check</td>
<td class="two">checked</td>
<td class="three">checking</td>
</tr>
</table>
<form>
#input for first column
#input for second column
#input for third column
</form>

<div class="add">Add New Row</div> //on clicking add new row form gets open and there is save button to add new row
```

Comment: You wouldn't use handlebars, a client-side templating library, for this in the first place. Look at jQuery's `append()` http://api.jquery.com/append/, as in `$('table').append('<tr><td class="one"...</td></tr>');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is 3 years, 8 months too late for Kunal, but perhaps someone will benefit.

@Palpatim is correct, a bit of jquery does the trick.  I included the following in my handlebars view.

A button:

```
<button id="btnNewRow">Add New Row</button>
```

A script append a row to the table:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnNewRow').on('click', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $("#approverTable").find('tbody')
                .append($('<tr><td><input></td><td><input></td><td><input></td></tr>'))
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally remember you need jquery loaded either from a local copy or via a Content Delivery Network (CDN), so add the following (which I do in my handlebars layout rather than my view).

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```